# Does bootstrapV4's flex grow property has different sizes?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrapV4 in my project. I know 'flex-grow-1' is available which corresponds to flex-grow: 1. But flex-grow-2, flex-grow-3 seems not available.

Can you let me know if this class is available? If not, may I know the reason?

Comment: As of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink only `flex-grow-0` and `flex-grow-1` (plus their viewport-related siblings) are available.

Comment: You can always create your classes to enhence BS4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`flex-grow-*`** was added in bootstrap version **4.1**. 
In the current version(4.1.1), there is only **`flex-grow-1`** and **`flex-grow-0`**.

```css
.flex-grow-0 {
  -ms-flex-positive: 0 !important;
  flex-grow: 0 !important;
}

.flex-grow-1 {
  -ms-flex-positive: 1 !important;
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```

Responsive variations also exist for **`flex-grow-*`**

- **`.flex-sm-grow-*`**
- **`.flex-md-grow-*`**
- **`.flex-lg-grow-*`**
- **`.flex-xl-grow-*`**

---

FYI, it holds true for `flex-shirnk` too. There is only **`flex-shrink-1`**  and **`flex-shrink-0`** and the responsive variations of them.

```css
.flex-shrink-0 {
  -ms-flex-negative: 0 !important;
  flex-shrink: 0 !important;
}

.flex-shrink-1 {
  -ms-flex-negative: 1 !important;
  flex-shrink: 1 !important;
}
```